# Ruby thread fatal deadlock error

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I have this simple ruby code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'Thread'


queue = Queue.new

t = Thread.new do
  loop do
    user = queue.pop

    puts "Unqueued #{user.nickname}, running all scripts..."

    #do stuff
    user.run_all

    puts "Finished running all script for  #{user.nickname}, sleeping for 2"
    sleep 2

    queue << user    
  end
end

t.join
```

When I try to run it, it gives me this error:

```
deadlock 0x10ec549f0: sleep:-  - ./Machine.rb:9
deadlock 0x10ea46348: sleep:J(0x10ec549f0) (main) - ./Machine.rb:23
fatal: Thread(0x10ea46348): deadlock
    from ./Machine.rb:23:in `join'
    from ./Machine.rb:23
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from (irb):1
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: so it will be deleted next week? why? what did i do wrong? help me

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to pop something from a queue, and the queue is empty. Normally your thread will lock, waiting for another thread to push something there. But there is no other thread except for the main process waiting for your thread to finish. So what do you expect Ruby to do?

Comment: Ah I see. But If I am running this from irb, then that irb thread is alive, no?

Comment: So there's 3 threads in total, one is 't', second is main (waiting for 't' to finish) and third is the irb thread. and the irb thread is still running waiting for my input, maybe i push something in the queue.. Am I wrong?

Comment: There is no "irb thread", how are you going to push anything if irb is waiting for `t.join`

Comment: There isn't? So before I call require, what is running?